# Using gnuplot in tikzpicture environment using pgf-package

Tags: gnuplot, tikz-pgf

I´m trying to use `gnuplot` in the `tikzpicture` environment with the `pgf` package.

**Example**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\section{PGFPLOTS}
Note how the tick labels match the document font.

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-10:10, samples=50, smooth, no markers, enlargelimits=false]
\addplot gnuplot {sin(x)}; \addlegendentry{$\sin(x)$}
\addplot gnuplot {cos(x)}; \addlegendentry{$\cos(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I´m using MikTeX. I already changed the options for `pdflatex` from

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

to

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

as recommended on several websites and by MikTeX itself.

But still I get error lines like:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file
>   'pgf-external*data.pgf
>   -plot.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feat ure? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex
>   -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>> gnuplot .gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. See the pgfplots package
>   documentation for explanation.

for both

```
\addplot gnuplot ...
```

So here is what I did so far:

1. pdflatex -shell-escape in some variations. (--shell-escape, --enable-write18, -enable-write18)
2. checked the `PATH`. MikTeX and `gnuplot` path exist till the .exe files
3. various other things not so related to the problem

Edit:
When I try to create a pdf-file with the following code

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,version=last]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat= newest, width=10cm, }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=9cm,
width=9cm,
grid=minor,
]
\addplot gnuplot[id=filesuffix]{(-x**5 - 242)};
\addlegendentry{model}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the log file gives me

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.6.4)  21 JUN 2013 21:04
>   entering extended mode

Comment: No need to load `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}` as pgfplots generates the `file.gnuplot` required for gnuplot input for which it outputs `file.table`. [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) is another alternative route to embed pure gnuplot commands. Remember to run `pdflatex --enable-write18` twice to get the final pdf.It works on Linux, I am not able to test on MiKTeX, may be you can give a try. Even `\usepackage{pgfplotstable}` is not required.

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly, I had this problem because I had failed to first install `gnuplot`, and was making with `latexmk`. Installing it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It´s been at while but i couldn´t find the time untill now. So here ist what i have done to solve my problem.

**Example**

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper, headinclude, titlepage]{scrartcl}                
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                                     
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}                                                                                                                                                  
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}                                                                                                                 
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                           
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\usepackage{float}                                                              

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
     [  ylabel=$\kappa$ / (S/m) , xlabel=c / (mol/m$^3$), title=\textbf{c gegen $\kappa$}, 
        xmin=0, xmax=130,
        ymin=0,  ymax=0.3,
        width=0.6\textwidth, height=0.45\textwidth, x axis line style={-}, y axis line                     style={-},
      ]     
         \addplot [only marks, gray, raw gnuplot, id=raw3] function{plot 'Daten.txt' u 1:2};
             \addplot [orange, dashed, raw gnuplot, id=raw3] function{plot 'ber.txt' u 1:3};
     \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Auftragung der Messwerte c gegen $\kappa$ (grau) und der berechneten Werte (orange)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My configurations:
 - Gnuplot and LaTeX installed
 - path variable checked (windows)
 - included "-shell-escape" in the pdfLaTeX option (easy in texstudio)
 - ensured that the name of the texfile includes no space, umlauts or other special characters; otherwise the .table file is not created. 
 - If the memory of LaTeX is exceeded, swaped the plot in an extra file and included it in the main file

Run pdfLaTeX twice and voila there should be a plot like the one below.

Here is the **plot**:
[image: plot createt with gnuplot in latex]

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem as OP, came here via google. OPs answer did not resolve my issue.

Changing shell-escape from restricted to unrestricted mode worked. In TexLive you can do so by adding `shell_escape = t` to the `texmf.cnf` file in your texlive folder.
Alternatively, you can modify the `shell_escape_commands` option in `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following can be useful to anyone, but I just had the same problem, although I have tried the suggestions in this and other posts.

My document type is book (I don't think this is relevant) and my main `.tex` was called "notas_Estadística.tex". Note that this name has a "´" accent. I created another folder with the exactly the same files but the main now was called "try.tex". When I compiled it, all went well. After many tries I realized that it was the name of the main file that was causing the error. I guess that gnuplot program could have some problems with symbols and accents. In the original folder I changed the name for "notas_Estadistica.tex" and now all went well.