# Should I install gnuplot? : Error using gnuplot when \addplot+ is used

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

On page 42/571 of the pgfplots package there is an example using `\addplot+` and `gnuplot` as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [id=parable,domain=-5:5,] gnuplot {4*x**2 - 5} node [pin=180:{$4x^2-5$}]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I run using pdfLaTeX getting an error:

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file
> 'f2_addplot_pgfplots_p
>
> p42.parable.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the
> shell-escap
>
> e feature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can
> also invo
>
> ke '>> gnuplot .gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot
> file..
>
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
>
> Type  H   for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.9 ...t {4*x**2 - 5} node [pin=180:{$4x^2-5$}]{};

Do you know how to fix this? Should I install gnuplot?

Comment: Hav you checked here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120218/using-gnuplot-in-tikzpicture-environment-using-pgf-package?rq=1) if you have installed and configured everything correctly?

Comment: Checked but couldn’t understand. Should I reinstall my latex ?

Comment: Besides having a working LaTeX installation you need two more requirements to make the example compile without error messages. 1. You need to have gnuplot installed and it should be reachable from command line (e.g. open the Command Prompt `cmd` and type `gnuplot --version` which should return something similar to `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8`). 2. You need to run pdflatex with shell-escape, i.e. `pdflatex -shell-escape ...` or `pdflatex --enable-write18 ...`.

Comment: Thanks how to run pdflatex with -shell/escape?

Comment: That depends ... If you run it "by hand" you simply type this option, if you use an editor it depends on the editor. If you are lucky this is answered here on TeX.SX. Try searching for `enable shell escape` + your editor. Maybe you can find it in the help of your editor or another resource of your editor. Let us know if you were successful. Good luck!

Comment: What software do you use to compile your .tex files?

Comment: Pdflatex software

Comment: @Aria Does this software has a specific name like TeXstudio, TeXMaker, ...

Comment: I use Texworks.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I installed gnuplot but got the same error when I run the code above. I use Texworks from Miktex. I do not know how to enable shell escape. Would you please help if you know? Thanks!

Comment: I can just repeat myself: Simply search for [`enable shell escape Texworks`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=enable+shell+escape+Texworks) here on TeX.SX ...